# Background methods always as private class?

Tags: java, android

I'm starting with Android and wonder if background Task like DB reading and saving are always encapsulated in private classes?

I mean, at the moment I have:

```
private class SaveToDB extends AsyncTask..
private class ReadFromDB extends AsyncTask..

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
 new SaveToDB().execute();
}
```

And so on. This way, I always have to create a new object if I want to execute background tasks. Is that the correct way?

What I wonder is that all my private classes are "actions" itself, not really objects. As they are named eg save or read which naming normally applies to methods by convention, not to classes.

Moreover, in case I'm doing it right: is it good practice to neast the private classes inside MyApplication Activity? Or should I refacter them out into own separate classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are firing of async tasks to interact with a sqlite database, then its not the best way to do things these days, you should check out cursor loaders instead.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

Once you got your head around them they are much easier than firing off async tasks, infact they build on top of async tasks to address some of the issues you describe and are tolerant to configuration changes.

I highly recommend to move away from AsyncTask (for db access) and use the Loader API instead.

Its backported in the compatibility package so you can use them in older versions prior to Honeycomb.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a service to handle all the background content management.  So, when you want to save, you just message the service and tell it to write data.  This is much more complicated.  For simple things, you can do it exactly as you are currently.

EDIT:

Also, as Ian pointed out, take a look at the new database interfacing classes post 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Not always.

For example, if you've got a task that is to be used by different activities (I'm not talking about sharing the same instance), you will want a public class so you don't write it several times.

If you only use that (class of) task in one place, private class might help keeping your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is a correct way for using AsyncTask, which isntance you can execute once.
2. Class Name can be `DbSaver` isntead of `SaveToDb` for instance which is more readable.
3. If that class is used only one Activity you can nest them, why not. But if you have task which is executed within different Activities, it is a good idea to create his own file.

Answer (score 0):

It is good design to loosely couple your database access from your UI code. One way to avoid having to create a new object every time would be to make the database access classes a singleton and just return the instance of the class whenever you need to make a transaction.

To your last question it is a better idea to move the database management to its own class so that it can be accessed across several activities. If you do it all in a private class then what happens when you have a new activity that need s database access?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do this with `AsyncTask`.  Each instance of an `AsyncTask` can only be run once.  You need to create a new one every time.